# Pyspark filter top three matches when performing cosine similarity

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two collection of documents. I have computed cosine similarity between each pair of the cartesian product and got an RDD of the form

```
(k1,(k2,c))
```

Where k1 is a document from the first collection, k2 is one from the second and c is the cosine similarity between them.

I'm interested in getting, for each document k1 in the first collection, the three most similar from the second collection. I have performed a group by key:

```
grouped = (pairRddWithCosine
         .groupByKey()
         .map(lambda (k, v): (k, sorted(v, key=lambda x: -x[1])))
         .map(lambda (x,y): (x, y[0][0],y[0][1], y[1][0], y[1][1],         y[2][0] , y[2][1]))
      )
```

It turns out that this group by is performing very bad. Would you please tell me how could I tune it or even better, use something that do not shuffle the data?

Comment: Nice homework assignment. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a sum/count/part of the values for a key you should avoid groupByKey, because groupByKey shuffles all data so that all values for a given key end up in the same reducer. For large datasets this is very expensive. Instead you should use reduceByKey  or combineByKey. For these operations you could specify the function for accumulating data on each partition and the merge function between accumulators from different partitions. You can read this for more details: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `reduceByKey` because you're only interested in part of the values

```
k_with_top_c = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda v: sorted(v, key=lambda x: -x[1])[:3])
```

`reduceByKey` will try a local reduce first so it runs faster than `groupByKey`. However, I don't think you could avoid shuffle in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I think that if we take

```
smallRdd = pairRddWithCosine.map(lambda (k1,(k2,c)))
```

then

```
Combined = (smallRdd
        .combineByKey(lambda value: [value],
                      lambda x, value: x + [value],
                      lambda x, y : max(x,y))
        .map(lambda (x,y): (x,y[0]))
        .map(lambda x: (x,0))
       )
```

followed by a join would provide the first match. We may get all the elements from pairRddWithCosine  that are not best matches by performing a          leftOuterJoin() 
with the best matches to get the second best.